# How to fix python trying to import wrong module

Tags: python

So I am making a module called `soar` that takes complex(ish) operations and makes them easier (in my opinion). I am having a problem where it is trying to import the wrong thing from the `soar.py`.

Error:`ImportError: cannot import name 'Soar' from 'soar'`

soar.py:
    
`versionNo = "0.4.2"`
    
`author = "AbyssWalker240"`

```
#####

class Logger:

    def __init__(self):

        pass

    @classmethod

    def llog(cls, file, typeM, message):

        with open(file, "a") as llog_f:
            llog_f.write("\n" + typeM + ": " + message)

class Math:

    def __init__(self):

        pass

    @classmethod

    def add(cls, number1, number2):

        try:

            return number1 + number2

        except:

            print("Error: non-int variable detected. Please replace all strings/lists/floats or other with an int.")

    def sub(cls, number1, number2):

        try:

            return number1 - number2

        except:

            print("Error: non-int variable detected. Please replace all strings/lists/floats or other with an int.")

    def mul(cls, number1, number2):

        try:

            return number1 * number2

        except:

            print("Error: non-int variable detected. Please replace all strings/lists/floats or other with an int.")

    def div(cls, number1, number2):

        try:

            return number1 / number2

        except:

            print("Error: non-int variable detected. Please replace all strings/lists/floats or other with an int.")

class Soar:

    def __init__(self):

        pass

    @classmethod

    def version(cls):

        print(versionNo)

    def author(cls):

        print(author)

class Join:

    def __init__(self):

        pass

    @classmethod

    def sJoin(cls, str1, str2, spacedVal):

        if(spacedVal == 1):

            return str1, str2

        elif(spacedVal == 0):

            return str1 + str2

        else:

            print("Error: spacedVal should be either 1 (spaced) or 0 (not spaced)")
```

test.py:
    from soar import Join

```
joiner = Join()

str1 = "srting"

str2 = "gnitrs"

print(joiner.sJoin(str1, "hi man", 1))
print(joiner.sJoin("hi", str2, 0))
```

This issue occurs when I do `from soar import Logger`, `from soar import Math`, `from soar import Soar`, and/or `from soar import Join`. No matter which one I do. This issue started after I added Join.

This doesn't make sense to me as nowhere in any code given have I type `from soar import Soar`, and even if I did, I see no reason it should import that module.

I also know that there is no limit or anything blocking me from the amount of classes I have, so that cannot be the problem.

Comment: Do you have a circular dependency somewhere?

Comment: @0x5453 No I do not.